# word boundary in Emacs font lock keywords

Tags: emacs, elisp, font-lock

The following code fails to highlight `23`'s in `23-23` if pasted and evaluated in the scratch buffer, but not if done in a text buffer.

```
;; Example 1


'(1234 23 23-23 end)

(progn
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                          `(("\\b23\\b"
                             (0 'success))
                            "end"))
  (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
```

Why does it fail when `M-x isearch-forward-regexp RET \b23\b` still matches `23`'s in `23-23`?

Even if I change to the following code, only the first `23` in `23-23` gets highlighted.

```
;;; Example 2

'(1234 23 23-23 end)

(progn
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                          `((,(rx (or word-boundary
                                      "-")
                                  (group "23")
                                  (or word-boundary
                                      "-"))
                             (1 'success))
                            "end"))
  (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
```

Side note: "end" is there so that I can detect if the highlighter for 23 is ill formed. If it is ill formed or signals errors silently, end won't get highlighted.

---

```
;;; Example 3 (with xy instead of 23. also passing t and 'append.)
;;; if evaluated in the scratch buffer, it doesn't highlight xy in xy-xy

'(wxyz xy xy-xy end)

(progn
  (font-lock-add-keywords nil
                          `(("\\bxy\\b"
                             (0 'success t))
                            "end")
                          'append)
  (font-lock-fontify-buffer))
```

Comment: Modes may define their own chartables, where the meaning of the character may be defined differently (assigned to a different character class). In particular symbols such as hyphens, underscores, sigil sign (those which some times are counted toward word constituent and some times not) are subject to local modifications. You should probably examine the mode-local chartable and see what sytnax class is assigned to the character in question.

Comment: @wvxvw `M-x describe-syntax` says the syntax class for ASCII hyphen is symbol class both in lisp interaction mode (of the scratch buffer) and in text mode, in `emacs -Q`.

Comment: Not so long ago I came across a similar issue. What if you try replacing `\\b` with `\\<` `\\>` or `\\_<` and `\\_>`? I can't quite remember what the difference was.

Comment: @wvxvw  Example 4 in https://gist.github.com/jiyoo/6676050 adds a test with different word boundary notations and the same issue appears. According to the discussion following the selected answer, this seems to be a bug which got fixed or disappeared in dev versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that it does not in buffer `*scratch*` suggests that it is a problem with the current mode.  There are two main possibilities:

- What @wvcvw suggested: check what the syntax class of chars `2` and `3` is.
- The `font-lock-keywords` already defined for the mode interact with your code -- e.g., they override it.  Try adding `'APPEND` as a third arg to `font-lock-add-keywords`.  Try adding `t` as a `HIGHLIGHT` expression to your highlighter sexp (see the doc).  That should let your highlighting override any that might already be there otherwise.

BTW, you say it does not work in a "text buffer", but what does that mean?  From `emacs -Q`, evaluating your code in a buffer in `text-mode` shows that it *does* work.  Investigate what your "text buffer" mode is and try the suggestions above (both bullets if necessary, but try the second one first).

Comment: Character syntax for 2 and 3 are word and that for the ASCII hyphen is symbol, in lisp interaction mode and in text mode, according to what `C-u C-x =` says from `emacs -Q`. I have added Example 3 with suggested overrides. On text mode buffers, I meant to say that highlighting does not fail in a text mode buffer, i.e., highlighting is successful. Still with the new Example 3 (from `emacs -Q`), `xy` inside `xy-xy` does not get highlighted in the scratch buffer.

Comment: When I do your example 3 in `emacs -Q` in a text-mode buffer, `xy` ***is*** highlighted in `xy-xy` (only the hyphen char is not highlighted). Same thing in Emacs-Lisp mode. If you do not see this from `emacs -Q`, try looking at `C-h v font-lock-keywords` to see what is going on. A bit hard to believe we would see such a difference from `emacs -Q`.  Are you perhaps using `emacs -Q -nw`? (Dunno whether that might make a difference.)

Comment: Since I am using Emacs on MS Windows, What I ran was `runemacs.exe -Q`. I tried using `set` instead of `append` in [Example 4](https://gist.github.com/jiyoo/6676050) to simplify things. When I evaluate the progn form in Example 4 in an emacs-lisp-mode buffer from `runemacs.exe -Q`, `xy` in `xy-xy` is not highlighted. Same with `ab-ab`. Value of `font-lock-keywords` doesn't seem to contain anything that might interfere. `isearch-forward-regexp` continues to recognize `xy` in `xy-xy` unlike the font lock.

Comment: I am using GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (i386-mingw-nt6.1.7601) in case if this is some kind of bug that is fixed in a later version

Comment: OK. 1) I see no example 4. 2) With example 3 in Emacs-Lisp mode in Emacs 24.4 (dev snapshot), I see no problem. With it in 24.3 (or prior) I see what you see: `xy-xy` does not have `xy` highlighted. Dunno which bug fix might have affected this. HTH.

Comment: Example 4 is a link in my comment.

Comment: Yes, I see it now. Same thing. This was apparently fixed after Emacs 24.3. You can try to check the Change Log to see if it was just a fix in a lisp file. If so, then you can try loading the code for that fix (e.g. the fixed function definition(s)) into Emacs 24.3, if you do not have access to a later Emacs build. Anyway, I think you have the answer: broken through Emacs 24.3, fixed afterward.